# Submit an application to a standalone spark cluster running in GCP from Python notebook

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am trying to submit a spark application to a standalone spark(2.1.1) cluster 3 VM running in GCP from my Python 3 notebook(running in local laptop) but for some reason spark session is throwing error "StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master sparkmaster:7077".

Environment Details: IPython and Spark Master are running in one GCP VM called "sparkmaster". 3 additional GCP VMs are running Spark workers and Cassandra Clusters. I connect from my local laptop(MBP) using Chrome to GCP VM IPython notebook in "sparkmaster"

Please note that terminal works:

```
bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.1 --master spark://sparkmaster:7077 ex.py 1000
```

Running it from Python Notebook:

```
import os
os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.1 pyspark-shell'

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark=SparkSession.builder.master("spark://sparkmaster:7077").appName('somatic').getOrCreate() #This step works if make .master('local')

df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka1:9092,kafka2:9092,kafka3:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "gene") \
  .load()
```

so far I have tried these:

0. I have tried to change spark master node spark-defaults.conf and spark-env.sh to add SPARK_MASTER_IP.
1. Tried to find the STANDALONE_SPARK_MASTER_HOST=hostname -f setting so that I can remove "-f". For some reason my spark master ui shows FQDN:7077 not hostname:7077
2. passed FQDN as param to .master() and os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"]

Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Can you connect to that host/port from your machine (the one on which `spark-submit` is run)? Could it be firewall rules that prevent the connection on port 7077?

Comment: I ran the spark-submit by doing ssh to the master node. Please note that  .master('local')  was fine which tells me that connection from my laptop running IPython notebook to spark master VM running in GCP is fine. The problem starts when I want to use the spark cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research I was able to resolve the conflict. It was due to a simple environment variable called SPARK_HOME. In my case it was pointing to Conda's /bin(pyspark was running from this location)  whereas my spark setup was present in a diff. path. The simple fix was to add
`export SPARK_HOME="/home/<<your location path>>/spark/"` to .bashrc file( I want this to be attached to my profile not to the spark session)

**How I have done it:**

Step 1: ssh to master node in my case it was same as ipython kernel/server VM in GCP

Step 2:

- cd ~
- sudo nano .bashrc
- scroll down to the last line and paste the below line
- export SPARK_HOME="/home/your/path/to/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/"
- ctrlX and Y and enter to save the changes

Note: I have also added few more details to the environment section for clarity.